# Checking and unchecking the checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a check box,

```
        <div class="large-12 eachRow" ng-repeat="role in bindRoles">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{role.View}}"/>
        </div>
```

It binds the value correctly as in "bindRoles"

How can i perform two way binding? (For instance, Initially value of "role.View" if true and if i uncheck how can i make it reflect in bindRoles Json?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="role.View" />
```